# Visual Studio Page Inspector Assembly not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly, page-inspector

I have a ASP MVC Project which I didn't make but I need to upload it on a IIS server. This works but when I upload it and visit the website I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Everything works locally but not on the server. Things I tried already:

- Repairing .NET Framework
- Trying to remove 2 lines from .NET Framework webconfig (Located in: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config) file but can't because file is in use. Can't stop process because of Access Denied error

I found that removing these 2 lines might be a solution but I can't remove them:

```
<remove assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Is there something I am missing? Any help is much appreciated! Thx

Comment: If the web.config is somehow in use, how are you uploading the site?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the webconfig of .NET Framework. Will edit the question.

Comment: With that access denied error, is there an Admin about that can kill the process?

Comment: I should have all rights to the computer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding just this line to your site `web.config`. The config files are inherited from the .NET base up to you site and then folders in your site. So Your site will override the .NET framework config.

```
<remove assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

**EDIT**

The line should go here...

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation>
         <assemblies>
            <remove assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         </assemblies>
      </compilation>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It should be noted that all that junk in the `assembly` attribute more than likely needs to be identical to the one that adds it in the .NET framework config.

Comment: I actually already tried that but then I get a server error page.

Comment: that sounds like a config error.. in a MVC config file you will already have a compilation section.. it will look similar to `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />` you need to change it to `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"><assemblies></assemblies></compliation>` and the remove line inside that

Comment: It will be under all the binding redirects

Comment: Yes! That fixed it. I just noticed it myself too. Thx for the help!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That fixed the error for me. The reason is very similar i have VS 2015 and i installed VS 2017 but when i uninstalled VS 2017 the error appeared